Ubuntu 24.04 second monitor lost after suspend
Just installed Ubuntu 24.04 fresh. I have a laptop with an external display connected via HDMI and I'm experiencing the following issue:

After waking up the laptop from suspend mode, the external screen is no longer detected.
Even removing and re-plugging the HDMI cable doesn't trigger any detection.

The only solution seems to be restarting the system to regain display functionality.
Any ideas for this?

Not detected or turned off systemwise (see in Settings/Display)?

for AMD the following helped me. check if new drivers are available
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall


if not then try the following and unplug and re-plug the monitors
sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu


Thanks! actually the problem has been solved just by updating ubuntu software via gnome ubuntu updater.

This has been a longstanding issue for me and this actually solved it.  Can't believe it was such a simple fix.  Now I can finally wake up my laptop using the doc without opening it - unsuspending, then unplugging and re-plugging the doc cable. Huge quality of life improvement.

I had the same problem. Try going to "Software & Updates" app and in "Additional Drivers" tab switch to Nvidia driver ("NVIDIA driver metapackage from ndvidia-driver-535 (proprietary, tested)" worked for me). After restart the second display should work.

I had the same issue and tried so many suggestions but no chance.
Today I switched from using the HDMI cable to DisplayPort one. I'm not 100% sure why but the problem seemed to be resolved. Hope that helps for anyone looking for a workaround.
